# updating a table from inner query is only using the first value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an sql table like this:

Table Users

```
  Id         Name         Country          rank            total
+----+---------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
  1          John          Canada                           
  2          Kate          Canada                           
  3          Mark          Canada                           
  4          Max           Argentina                        
  5          Sam           Argentina                        
  6          Stacy         China                            
  7          Ken           China                            
  8          jack          China                            
  9          Don           China
```

I want to fill the `rank` and `total` values as follows:

```
  Id         Name         Country          rank            total
+----+---------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
  1          John          Canada           1                3
  2          Kate          Canada           2                3
  3          Mark          Canada           3                3
  4          Max           Argentina        1                2
  5          Sam           Argentina        2                2
  6          Stacy         China            1                4
  7          Ken           China            2                4
  8          jack          China            3                4
  9          Don           China            4                4
```

The total is basically the total number of each country and the rank is just just a count 1,2,3,4.... in that country (it reset for each one).

To do it I tried the following:

```
update Users
 set rank=u.tempRank, total=u.tempTotal
from
(select *,
         row_number() over (partition by [Country] order by newid()) as tempRank,
         count(*) over (partition by [Country]) as tempTotal
  from Users) as u
```

However the `rank` and the `total` are all equal the first tempRank and tempTotal and I get this table

```
  Id         Name         Country          rank            total
+----+---------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
  1          John          Canada           1                3
  2          Kate          Canada           1                3
  3          Mark          Canada           1                3
  4          Max           Argentina        1                3
  5          Sam           Argentina        1                3
  6          Stacy         China            1                3
  7          Ken           China            1                3
  8          jack          China            1                3
  9          Don           China            1                3
```

If I try to debug the inner query alone:

```
select *,
         row_number() over (partition by [Country] order by newid()) as tempRank,
         count(*) over (partition by [Country]) as tempTotal
  from Users
```

without updating, just selecting, I get correct results:

```
  Id         Name         Country          tempRank        tempTotal
+----+---------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
  1          John          Canada           1                3
  2          Kate          Canada           2                3
  3          Mark          Canada           3                3
  4          Max           Argentina        1                2
  5          Sam           Argentina        2                2
  6          Stacy         China            1                4
  7          Ken           China            2                4
  8          jack          China            3                4
  9          Don           China            4                4
```

So the problem is with the update, it is only taking the first row and updating all the table based on it.

How can I iterate through each row to update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the `update` like this:

```
with toupdate (
    select *,
           row_number() over (partition by [Country] order by newid()) as tempRank,
           count(*) over (partition by [Country]) as tempTotal
    from Users
   )
update toupdate
   set rank = tempRank, total = tempTotal;
```

This makes use of a very nice feature of SQL Server where you can update and "updatable CTE".

The problem with your query is that you have two tables that are not joined.  I think you can simplify it to:

```
update u
   set rank=u.tempRank, total=u.tempTotal
   from (select *,
                row_number() over (partition by [Country] order by newid()) as tempRank,
                count(*) over (partition by [Country]) as tempTotal
         from Users
        ) u;
```

Otherwise, you need to join them together:

```
update users
   set rank=u.tempRank, total=u.tempTotal
   from (select *,
                row_number() over (partition by [Country] order by newid()) as tempRank,
                count(*) over (partition by [Country]) as tempTotal
         from Users
        ) u
   where users.id = u.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Update u set
    rank = (select count(*) from users
            where country = u.country 
               and id <= u.Id),
    total = (Select count(*) from users
             where country = u.country)
From users u
```